# How do I get purchase order name, vendor name, product name and scheduled date from purchase orders in Odoo 11?

Tags: python, odoo, erp, purchase-order

I'm kinda new to odoo and I'm trying to get Company wise purchase order name, vendor name, name of the prooduct and it's scheduled date based on the condition where scheduled date = **a particular date eg: 30-04-2021**, status= purchase or done and Quantity - received_qty = 0 (ie., products which are not fully received).

Here, is the function that I wrote.

**Note**: I haven't added the quantity condition yet.

```
    def get_purchase_order_expiry_date(self):
    company_list = []
    current_date = datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0)
    curr_start_date = current_date.replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=0)
    curr_end_date = current_date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=0)

    for rec in self:
        lang = self.env.context.get("lang")
        langs = self.env['res.lang']
        if lang:
            langs = self.env['res.lang'].search([("code", "=", lang)])
        format_date = langs.date_format or '%B-%d-%Y'
        current_date2 = str(current_date)
        new_date = datetime.strptime(current_date2, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT) + relativedelta(
            days=rec.expiry_offset)
        new_start_date = new_date.replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00)
        new_end_date = new_date.replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59)
        company_ids = self.env['res.company'].search([])
        for company in company_ids:
            expiring_po = self.env['purchase.order'].search(
                ['&', '|', '&', ('date_planned', '>=', str(new_start_date)),
                 ('date_planned', '<=', str(new_end_date)),
                 ('date_planned', '>=', str(curr_start_date)),
                 ('date_planned', '<=', str(curr_end_date)),
                 ('state', 'in', ['purchase', 'done']),
                 ('company_id', '=', company.id)])

            if expiring_po:
                po_list = []
                for p_orders in expiring_po:
                    due_date = datetime.strptime(p_orders.date_planned, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT).strftime(
                        format_date)
                    po_list.append({'product_name': p_orders.product_id.name,
                                    'po_name': p_orders.name,
                                    'vendor_name': p_orders.partner_id.name,
                                    'scheduled_date': due_date})
                if po_list:
                    company_list.append({'company_name': company.name,
                                         'expiring_po': po_list})
    return company_list
```

These are the fields in the order line of purchase order.

[image: One2many field image]
Can somebody tell me where it's going wrong?

Comment: Please explain error or issue you are facing after writing these lines of code? I am unable to understand what `output` are you expecting out of this.

Comment: I'm trying to create an e-mail template with data from company_list. But when I preview the template, the html part where where I show the data from company_list as a table is empty. When I checked, I noticed that nothing is going into expiring_po. The search is returning nothing. I edited the scheduled date of some purchase orders specifically to show up when searching, but still nothing is stored inside expiring_po